# Why is the diagonal continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $e\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous map with dense image in $Y$ and $m\colon Z\to W$ is a continuous embedding, i.e., $m$ describes a homeomorphism between $Z$ and its image equipped with the subspace topology of $W$. Suppose further, there exists continuous maps $f\colon X\to Z$ and $g\colon Y\to W$ such that $ge=mf$.

We define a set map $h\colon Y\to Z$ by setting $h=m^{-1}g$ (noting injectivity of $m$). We want to show $h$ is continuous.

If $U\subseteq Z$ is open, then $h^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}m(U)=ef^{-1}(U)$. So I am reduced to showing either $m$ or $e$ is an open map. However, neither embeddings nor epimorphisms (continuous maps with dense images) need be open. So I am stuck.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Compositions of continuous functions are continuous.  Since $m$ is an embedding, it's inverse is continuous.

Comment: Yes! Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing something quite simple (although you noticed virtually everything else):

Since $m$ is an embedding, as you noticed it is a homeomorphism between $Z$ and its image as a subspace of $W$, call it $W_0$.  But this means that $m^{-1} : W_0 \to Z$ is continuous, and so $h$ is continuous as it is a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: No worries: we all miss simple things from time to time.

Comment: Do we also need that $im(g)\subseteq im(m)$ so that the factorization through the subset makes sense?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff: Yes, in order for $m^{-1}g$ to have domain $Y$ then we would need that condition. By the commutativity we know that $f = m^{-1}ge$.  If $\mathrm{im}(m) = W_0$ were a _closed_ subspace, then everything would work out because $\mathrm{im}(e)$ is dense in $Y$. If $W_0$ is not closed, I'm not exactly certain how to continue.